# Apply CSS transition property on div with javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

I have used `javascript` code to increase and decrease the height of div on click event. But i also want to apply transition-duration property so that transition goes smoothly.

Here is the css code

```
#content {
    height: auto;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#F30;
    transition-duration:2s;
}

#content.expand {
    height: 300px;
    transition-duration:2s;
}
```

This is the javascript code

```
function chk()
{
    var node = document.getElementById('content');

    node.classList.toggle('expand');
}
```

The function is working properly. I have applied transition property, but that is not working.

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/Lw76f/ - What's the problem?

Comment: if you are trying on safari you need to wirte  -webkit-transition-duration :2s;

Comment: @Terror.Blade Transition is not working in mozilla. Works fine in chrome and safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Bugzilla, this is the <kbd>[Bug 571344](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=571344)</kbd>.

Transition to and from `auto` affects Firefox (that doesn't transition *at all*), but works in quirks ways in other browsers too.

For example, in Chrome `height: auto` is treated like `height: 0` in the transition, and you will see the red background of the example being smaller up to disappear, then restoring to the real "auto" value.

Simply specify an height, and it will work good, in every browser: <kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw76f/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try cross browser solution like this:

```
 transition-duration:2s; 
 -o-transition-duration:2s; 
 -moz-transition-duration:2s; 
 -webkit-transition-duration:2s;
```

instead of only `transition-duration:2s;`

Comment: Its still not working in mozilla. It increases and decreases in a sudden. No effect of transition property.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the value transform, in Mozilla it is prefixed with -moz-transform.

```
#content {
    height: auto;
    width:400px;
    background-color:#F30;
    -webkit-transition:all .1s ease;
 -moz-transition:all .1s ease;
 -ms-transition:all .1s ease;
 transition:all .1s ease;
}

#content.expand {
    height: 300px;
   -webkit-transition:all .1s ease;
 -moz-transition:all .1s ease;
 -ms-transition:all .1s ease;
 transition:all .1s ease; 
}
```

Comment: where should i put the time duration? can you please show me?

Comment: checked it. still not working. Its working in chrome, but not in mozilla.

Comment: Your efforts are great @Terror.Blade, but that is not working. Can you please check this in your mozilla browser. It may be due to some problem in browser.